# Is anyone aware of a good exposition of the Gauss-Kramer model of Integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

In the Princeton Companion of Mathematics, the Analytic Number Theory section, the author mentions what he calls Gauss-Kramer model, which is simply modeling the integers on a countable sequence of random variables $\{ X_{n} \}$, where the variable $X_{n}$ has probability of $1/log(n)$ of being 1 and otherwise 0. Each variable $X_{n}$ represents whether the number n is prime or not. The Gauss-Kramer model conjectures that statements about the distribution of primes correspond to the statements on the countable collection of random variables with probability 1 of being true.

Question: Is anyone aware of a good exposition of the Gauss-Kramer model and any attempt to make it more rigorous using Model Theory or through other routes?

Comment: Usually written Cramer. I remember this MO question $$ $$
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36897/probabilistic-interpretation-of-prime-number-theorem
$$ $$
I will look for others. To answer your second question, it is known to be faulty by 1985 work of Meier. 

Comment: Alright, Maier. see $$ $$
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11978/heuristically-false-conjectures  $$ $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I am reading the synopsis of Meier's work currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 3 of The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution by Gérald Tenenbaum and Michel Mendès France has a nice exposition of the model, including modifications indicated by Maier's discovery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Has there been any attempt to make the model more rigorous? 

Comment: I don't think there has been much hope of making it rigorous, because the conclusions it yields are so far beyond what can be proved today. 
For example, if $p_k$ denotes the k-th prime, it is known that 
$p_{k+1} = p_k + O(p_k^{\alpha + \varepsilon})$ with $\alpha = 0.525$. The Riemann Hypothesis would allow $\alpha = 0.5$. But the 
Cramér model would yield $p_{k+1} = p_k + O(\log^2(p_k))$. 

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at:

1) "Harold Cramér and the distribution of prime numbers" by Andrew Granville
http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/cramer.pdf

2) "The distribution of prime numbers" by K. Soundararajan
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606408v1